# De\Serialization of two different class

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to serialize two distinct class in one file using BinaryFormatter, at this moment i can serialize one , all the classes have [serializable] just need to understand how like "merge" those classes

i just need to serialize the agência and autocarro in the same file...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace EDJD_AgênciaViagens
{    
class Dados
{
    private static Agência agência = new Agência("Agência IPCA", "Barcelos");
    // por motivos de erro 
    // criei nova entrada para autocarros        
    private static Autocarro autocarro = new Autocarro("IPCA", "Barcelos");

    public static Agência dados
    { get { return agência; } }
    //entrada para autocarros independete das viagens
    public static Autocarro auto
    { get { return autocarro; } }       

}
}
```

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is not recommended for static data storage. It is extremely fickle to version differences and you may end up not being able to open up the file you created previously. What are you using `BinaryFormatter` to do?

Answer (score 3):

Define a new class that will aggregate the 2 classes as properties. Now serialize this new class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyModel
{
    public Class1 Class1 { get; set }
    public Class2 Class2 { get; set }
}
```

There you go, now serialize an instance of `MyModel` which will contain the 2 other classes and you will have all the necessary information:

```
// get instances of your classes
Class1 class1 = ... get your instance of class1
Class2 class2 = ... get your instance of class2

// now build the new class
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.Class1 = class1;
model.Class2 = class2;

// and then serialize the new model
using (var stream = File.Create("data.bin"))
{
    var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    serializer.Serialize(stream, model);
}
```

and when later you want to deserialize this class:

```
using (var stream = File.Create("data.bin"))
{
    var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    MyModel model = (MyModel)serializer.Serialize(stream);

    Class1 class1 = model.Class1;
    Class2 class2 = model.Class2;
}
```

Comment: Note that `BinaryFormatter` is very very fickle when trying to desearalize a file and you may not be able to open your `.bin` after a windows update occurs and changes any version numbers of assemblies in the .NET framework that your class relies on. It is strongly recommended to use some other form of serialization if you are needing to do static storage. (still giving a +1 for the correct solution to the problem though :) )

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, as soon as you are using the same version of the .NET framework for serializing and deserializing, it is guaranteed that there won't be any problems. No updates (Windows or whatever) would interfere. Binary serialization is the fastest serialization you might ever dream for. So it really has its uses. Of course it's important to also know its limitations (that you have already pointed out). Thanks for that.

Comment: But if a windows update happens you could loose all access to previously created `.bin` files, if those files are being used for anything other than short lived temporary storage to be accessed only on the same machine that created the file I would stay away from making files with `BinaryFormatter` (it is great for IPC on the same machine, but I would not trust it with my files (Having your app suddenly unable to open old save files was quite a learning experience)

Comment: No, that's wrong. You won't lose anything with a Windows update. You might have interoperability issues if you are using different versions of the .NET framework and the CLR for serializing and deserializing. It's as simple as that. You might do as many updates and OS changes as you want, as soon as you have the same CLR, you are safe.

Comment: Yes, any ***new*** files you create can be desearlized, but what about the last 2 years of save files your program has been generating that are now un-openable?

Comment: Dude, who said that I upgraded .NET version for the last 2 years? When I have to upgrade the version of .NET for some application I take into account things like that -> whether this application is using binary serialization or not. It's one of the constraints already mentioned. I know what you mean. It's just that you have to be more precise when making conclusions about something. You just cannot generalize that people should not use binary serialization because they will loose the last 2 years of saved files.